# How to UnitTest MongoItemReader in springbatch? why adding Criteria to query makes MongoItemReader injected bean null?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-batch

I want to unit test the MongoItemReader part of springbatch so

for testing

```
@Autowired
MongoItemReader mongoItemReader;

@Test
public void readerTest() throws Exception {

    assertNotNull(mongoItemReader.read());

}
```

Is it enough for testing reader? and is there a way to get the read data in test cases from reader? cause doPageRead() in MongoItemReader.java is protected, that is why I can not test the read data

Also in the reader bean :

```
    @Bean
    public MongoItemReader<User> userReader() {
        userRepository.save(USER_SAMPLE);

        Map<String, Sort.Direction> sort = new HashMap<>();
        sort.put("_id", Sort.Direction.ASC);

        return new MongoItemReaderBuilder<User>().template(this.mongoTemplate)
                .targetType(User.class)
                .saveState(false).pageSize(10)
                .jsonQuery(String.format("{Dep: '%s'}", department))
                .sorts(sort).template(mongoTemplate)
                .name("users")
                .build();
    }
```

when I replace `.jsonQuery(String.format("{Dep: '%s'}", department))` with `

.query(query)

`

and query is :

```
        Query query = new Query().with(PageRequest.of(0, 10)).with(Sort.by(Sort.Direction.ASC, "_id"));
        query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("Dep").is(departmentValue));
```

it does not pass the test until I remove the last line of criteria

why adding criteria conditions to query object in reader bean makes `assertNotNull(mongoItemReader.read());` failling

Comment: How is it failing? What is the error?

Comment: when I add query object with criteria i got this assertion    ```assertNotNull(mongoItemReader.read());```  failing because mongoItemReader.read() is null